# Simultaneous transmission on ad hoc wifi

Tags: wireless

In a NS3 network simulation, I'm trying to transmit packets from 40 echo clients to a central echo server using OLSR routing on 802.11 simultaneously.

However, only eight of these packets are consistently received by the server. ([Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYGes.png))

If, however, I try to serve the packets individually at an interval of 0.1s from each station, it seems to work fine.

Is this a protocol limit?

Sorry, I'm kind of new to networking but I tried to explain it as well as I could.

> Please wait, populating routing tables (30s)....
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32s client sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32.0029s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.3 port 49153
>   At time 32.0029s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.3 port 49153
>   At time 32.0089s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.5 port 49153
>   At time 32.0089s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.5 port 49153
>   At time 32.0108s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.12 port 49153
>   At time 32.0108s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.12 port 49153
>   At time 32.0299s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.13 port 49153
>   At time 32.0299s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.13 port 49153
>   At time 32.0317s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32.0631s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 32.0651s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 33.0049s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 33.0158s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.25 port 49153
>   At time 33.0158s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.25 port 49153
>   At time 33.0294s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.18 port 49153
>   At time 33.0294s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.18 port 49153
>   At time 33.038s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.28 port 49153
>   At time 33.038s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.28 port 49153
>   At time 33.0495s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 33.0611s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 33.068s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9
>   At time 34.0066s server received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.41 port 49153
>   At time 34.0066s server sent 1024 bytes to 10.1.3.41 port 49153
>   At time 34.0153s client received 1024 bytes from 10.1.3.1 port 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

802.11 is CSMA/CA, so there is no "simultaneous transmission."  Stations wait until the channel is clear and then begin transmitting.  So only one station transmits at a time.  My guess is some of your stations never see an idle channel.

Comment: Normally, a stochastic backoff algorithm is applied specifically to avoid these stalls ...

Comment: I agree.  I wonder, though, how well his simulator simulates that.